# Spring Boot, Status 404, Error "Not Found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

the second day I can not solve the problem related to the 404th status. I watched articles about this problem, most of them had a problem with the folder hierarchy, but everything seems to be fine with me :'(

**Folder sctructure**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7rUE.png)

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.training</groupId>
    <artifactId>regplustext</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>regplustext</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UserRestController**

```
package com.training.regplustext.controller;

import com.training.regplustext.entity.UserRegistrationEntity;
import com.training.regplustext.exception.AccountNotFound;
import com.training.regplustext.exception.NullRegistrationException;
import com.training.regplustext.service.UserService;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/welcome-page/")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserRestController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("registration-page/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> regPage(@RequestBody UserRegistrationEntity newUser, @RequestParam Long id) {
        try{
            userService.registration(newUser.getUsername(), newUser.getPassword());
            return ResponseEntity.ok("{id} id registration has passed successfully!");
        }catch (NullRegistrationException ex){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("login-page/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> loginPage(@RequestBody UserRegistrationEntity user, @PathVariable Long id){
        try{
            userService.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
            return ResponseEntity.ok("{id} id login has passed successfully!");
        }catch (AccountNotFound ex){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**UserRegistrationEntity**

```
package com.training.regplustext.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "UserRegistrationEntity")
@Table(name = "user_registration_table")
@Data
public class UserRegistrationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "username",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String username;

    @Column(
            name = "password",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String password;
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package com.training.regplustext.repository;

import com.training.regplustext.entity.UserRegistrationEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRegistrationEntity, Long> {

    Optional<UserRegistrationEntity>findUserRegistrationEntityByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

**UserService**

```
package com.training.regplustext.service;

import com.training.regplustext.entity.UserRegistrationEntity;
import com.training.regplustext.exception.AccountNotFound;
import com.training.regplustext.exception.NullRegistrationException;

public interface UserService {

    UserRegistrationEntity registration(String username, String password) throws NullRegistrationException;
    UserRegistrationEntity login(String username, String password) throws AccountNotFound;
}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
package com.training.regplustext.service;

import com.training.regplustext.entity.UserRegistrationEntity;
import com.training.regplustext.exception.AccountNotFound;
import com.training.regplustext.exception.NullRegistrationException;
import com.training.regplustext.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserRegistrationEntity registration(String username, String password) throws NullRegistrationException{
        if(username == null || password == null)
            throw new NullRegistrationException("username or password is nullable");
        else{
            UserRegistrationEntity newUser = new UserRegistrationEntity();
            newUser.setUsername(username);
            newUser.setPassword(password);

            return userRepository.save(newUser);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserRegistrationEntity login(String username, String password) throws AccountNotFound{
        if(userRepository.findUserRegistrationEntityByUsernameAndPassword(
                username,
                password
        ).isEmpty())
            throw new AccountNotFound("account not found, please register first");
        else{
            return userRepository.findUserRegistrationEntityByUsernameAndPassword(
                    username,
                    password
            ).orElse(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**RegplustextApplication**

```
package com.training.regplustext;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.training.regplustext.repository")

public class RegplustextApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegplustextApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reg_plus_text
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
server.port=8081
```

**postman**

[postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ioEp.png)

Comment: We can check following on 404
1. Check the startup logs(we can get more info in case of any failures on bean creation) 2. Check whether endpoints created successfully
3. Server may not able to bind the port which is configured in properties file As debugging step
1. Create some simple echo endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the @ComponentScan("com.training.regplustext.repository") path?

It should include all Component's like @Component, @Controller, @Service, @Repository, @Configuration, @RestController.

Please change it to @ComponentScan("com.training.regplustext").